# How to recover pv(Released) data after pvc deletion

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a kubernetes cluster on the eks of aws. I use aws-ebs as the Provisioner of StorageClass, and the ReclaimPolicy is set to Retain. I install the application with helm. When I delete the application, the pvc is deleted, but the pv still exists. The status is Released. I can see that the aws-ebs volume is still in the aws console. Now I want to create a new application and still use the original data. I think there are two ways to do it

1. Manually create a pvc to bind this pv to make pv work again, but the StorageClass cannot be used
2. Re-create a new PV to bind aws-ebs and then create a new PVC through this PV, it seems that StorageClass cannot be used

But I don’t know how to change it, can I ask for help?   thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ReclaimPolicy: Retain](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain) means that:

> The `Retain` reclaim policy allows for manual reclamation of the
> resource. When the PersistentVolumeClaim is deleted, the
> PersistentVolume still exists and the volume is considered "released".
> But it is not yet available for another claim because the previous
> claimant's data remains on the volume. An administrator can manually
> reclaim the volume with the following steps.
>
> 1. Delete the PersistentVolume. The associated storage asset in external infrastructure (such as an AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or
>    Cinder volume) still exists after the PV is deleted.
> 2. Manually clean up the data on the associated storage asset accordingly.
> 3. Manually delete the associated storage asset, or if you want to reuse the same storage asset, create a new PersistentVolume with the
>    storage asset definition.

[Here](https://rtfm.co.ua/en/kubernetes-persistentvolume-and-persistentvolumeclaim-an-overview-with-examples/#Deleting_PV_and_PVC_%E2%80%93_an_example) you can find an example showing step by step how to manually reuse a PV after PVC was deleted the way that the data will not be lost.

Comment: @gophergfer Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: I created a new pvc and set its volumeName to the name of pv. Then I modified the name, namespace, uid and resourceVersion of the claimRef of the pv to be consistent with the new pvc. Run

Comment: If PV does not exist, you can connect to aws ebs by modifying this value awsElasticBlockStore.volumeID